# Code for solving the heat equation on the semi-infinite rod

Tags: pde, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, differential-equations

**Cross posted [in mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157983/1871).**

---

**Question** : I want to test the solution which is given below is right by Matlab/Maple/Mathematica.

Please look [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473201/how-to-solve-heat-equation-on-the-semi-infinite-rod-by-fourier-transform/2476391#2476391) in mathstackexhange

or

Please look below.

**Q:** Solve the following heat equation on the semi-infinite rod

$$u_t=ku_{xx}$$ where $x,t>0$ and
    $u_x(0,t) =0$ and $u(x,0)=\begin{cases} 
      1, & 0 < x <2 \\
      0, &  2\leq x  
   \end{cases}
$

**Answer**

We found the following answer 
$$
u(x,t) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-s^2 t}\frac{1-\cos(2s)}{s}\cos(sx)ds.
$$

**Code**

But I am not sure the solution is right. I am not capable of to write a code in order to test it. Could you help me?

Comment: You could use a [chebfun](http://www.chebfun.org/) and then compute the integral.